# Python & tkinter, experiencing a memory leak when opening and closing a dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, memory-leaks

I'm writing a GUI to interface with a database. The GUI requires the user to log in. If the attempted connection to the database fails, I create an error dialog. I have been watching task manager and each time an error dialog pops up, the memory used by the program jumps a bit. I think I might have a misunderstanding about tkinter. Any help is appreciated. All relevant code is below. I think I have pin-pointed the leak to the `except` within `LogInWindow.enter_cb()`. I know the class is not indented properly. Couldn't format the text properly.

The main function starts the LogInWindow on a `mainloop`.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ErrorWindow(Tk):
"""Window for displaying database log in errors"""
def __init__(self, exception):
    Tk.__init__(self)

    self.title('MySQL Error')
    self.resizable(False, False)

    error = Text(self, height=2, wrap=WORD, relief=FLAT)
    error.insert(END, 'MySQL {!r}'.format(exception))
    error.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
    error.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
    error.config(state=DISABLED)
    error.configure(bg=self.cget('bg'))
    error.pack(padx=5, pady=(5, 0))

    ok = ttk.Button(self, text='OK', command=self._quit)
    ok.bind('<Return>', self._quit)
    ok.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    # root.grab_set()
    ok.focus_set()

def _quit(self, *args):
    self.destroy()


class LogInWindow(Tk):
"""Window for getting the user's database credentials"""

connection = None

def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)

    self.title('Enter Credentials')
    self.resizable(False, False)

    main_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)

    entry_frame = ttk.Frame(main_frame)
    entry_frame.pack()

    u_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text='Username')
    p_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text='Password')
    self.usern = ttk.Entry(entry_frame)
    self.passw = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, show='*')

    self.usern.bind('<Return>', self.enter_cb)
    self.passw.bind('<Return>', self.enter_cb)

    u_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=5)
    self.usern.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 15), pady=5)
    p_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=5)
    self.passw.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(0, 15), pady=5)

    button_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
    button_frame.pack()

    enter = ttk.Button(button_frame, text='Enter', command=self.enter_cb)
    cancel = ttk.Button(button_frame, text='Cancel', command=self.cancel_cb)

    enter.bind('<Return>', self.enter_cb)
    cancel.bind('<Return>', self.cancel_cb)

    enter.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)
    cancel.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.usern.focus_set()

def enter_cb(self, *args):
    """Enter callback for either creating a database connection or spewing an error dialog"""
    try:
        # make a conection with the database
        import pymysql.cursors
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                          user=self.usern.get(),
                                          password=self.passw.get(),
                                          db='databasename',
                                          charset='utf8mb4',
                                          cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        self.destroy()
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
        # create an error dialog
        error = ErrorWindow(e)
        center(error)
        error.mainloop()
        # del(error)

def cancel_cb(self, *args):
    """Cancel callback for destroying the window"""
    self.destroy()
```

Comment: your indentation is incorrect. Please try to fix it.

Comment: Yes I referenced this in the OP, but I can't put the class statements in within the code block without adding 4 spaces to every single line. Sorry. Is there a better way to do this? I have no experience with posting on SO

Comment: You can highlight all of your code and then click the button that looks like `{}` to indent everything with four spaces. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You can also highlight all your code and then press `CTRL+K` to get the same result as pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep the tips in mind for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least part of the problem is that you shouldn't have more than a single instance of `Tk`. If you are creating a dialog, it needs to be a subclass of `Toplevel`, not `Tk`.

A well designed tkinter program should explicitly create the root window (`Tk()`) exactly once, and call `mainloop` exactly once.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll make the appropriate adjustments. One other question. Should my log in window also be a subclass of `Toplevel`, while the actual program subclasses  `Tk`? Also I upvoted you I just don't have enough reputation. **Edit**: Thanks this fixed my issue!

Comment: I understand the relationship between `Tk` and `Toplevel`. Again thanks for the insight.